# My jsx file generates me callbackRef.current error

Tags: reactjs

my file StepperControl gives me error in my console log. Can someone see where is the problem ?

StepperControl.jsx:1 Uncaught TypeError: callbackRef.current is not a function at handler (StepperControl.jsx:1:1)

StepperControl.jsx:

```
export default function StepperControl({ handleClick, currentStep, steps }) {
    return (
        <div className="container mt-4 mb-8 flex justify-around">
            {
                currentStep > 1 &&
                <button
                    onClick={() => handleClick()}
                    className={`cursor-pointer rounded-md border-2 border-slate-300 bg-white py-2 px-3 text-slate-400 transition duration-200 ease-in-out 
                    hover:bg-slate-700 hover:text-white opacity-50`}
                >
                    Back
                </button>
            }
            <button
                onClick={() => handleClick("next")}
                className="cursor-pointer rounded-md bg-primary-700 py-2 px-3 text-white transition duration-200 ease-in-out hover:bg-blue-700 hover:text-white"
            >
                {currentStep === steps.length - 1 ? "Confirm" : "Next"}
            </button>

        </div>
    );
}
```

I use it here also :

```
export default function App() {
...
const handleClick = (direction) => {
        let newStep = currentStep;    
        direction === "next" ? newStep++ : newStep--;
        // check if steps are within bounds
        newStep > 0 && newStep <= steps.length && setCurrentStep(newStep);
    };
  return (
   ...          
      </div>
      {currentStep !== steps.length && (
        <StepperControl
          handleClick={handleClick}
          currentStep={currentStep}
          steps={steps}
        />
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Likely you have it in parenting component…

Comment: Hi, yes I've edited my issue I use it in App.js

Answer (score 0):

in app() you write defaut, not default

Comment: Hi, the error still there...

Comment: where is the function handleClick declared?

Comment: sorry it's an error, I've modified

Comment: can you show the full code of the app() component?

Comment: should handleclick be able to take currentStep from the StepperControl component?

Comment: Here the full [code](https://codesandbox.io/s/amazing-golick-glgf2c?file=/src/App.js:0-1823) and yes handleClick should be able to do that

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244761/discussion-between-alexincube-and-zokulko).

Comment: I've send you a message in the discussion, don't know if you receive the notif (for my part I don't receive them...)